# Question about "Gibbs Sampler Derivation for Latent Dirichlet Allocation"

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I am reading a document about "Gibbs Sampler Derivation for Latent Dirichlet Allocation" by Arjun Mukherjee. Following is the url of the paper:
[http://www2.cs.uh.edu/~arjun/courses/advnlp/LDA_Derivation.pdf](http://www2.cs.uh.edu/%7Earjun/courses/advnlp/LDA_Derivation.pdf)

I have a question about Equation (16) of the paper,

[This link is a picture of part of Equation (16)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLXNg.jpg)

How the denominator of this step is derived? Why are they independent?
Can this relation be obtained by Bayesian Network of LDA? By d-separation?
Several authors are very vague about this step.

Can anyone explain how this step is derived clearly?

Answer (score 0):

The authors rearranged the denominator using the chain rule, which allows you to express the joint probability using the conditional probabilities (you can derive them by looking at the graphical representation of LDA).

Comment: I cannot figure out how the independency is implied by the graphical representation of LDA, please show it explicitly.